# Openstreetmap , Leaflet.js: Open all popup box on page load alwayes

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

is there any way popup always stay open ? Not having the need to click on it to open.
Openstreetmap , Leaflet: Open all popup box on page load alwayes

my full JS code:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/82xvheqd/
```

```
        _fitting = setTimeout(function(){
            if(markerGroup.getBounds()._southWest !== undefined && markerGroup.getBounds()._northEast !== undefined){               

                mymap.fitBounds(markerGroup.getBounds(),{ pan: false,animate: false });
                mymap.invalidateSize(false);

            }
        },300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add first the marker to the map and then bind the popup, also add the option `closeOnClick: false`, that the popup's not closed when clicking on map

```
_mark = L.marker(latLon).addTo(markerGroup).bindPopup(_popUpFun, {autoClose: false, autoPan: false,closeOnClick: false}).openPopup();
```

Comment: thank you for reply. but it is not working. and now disapear all marker